# How to use "as if" correctly?

Tags: grammaticality

I want to write something imaginary like

> I am happy for the positive results as if I really helped in the treatment.

In fact, I am really happy, but I didn’t help in the treatment.
Which one is the correct one?

1. l am happy for the positive results as if I really helped in the treatment.
2. I am happy for the positive results as if I really had helped in the treatment.
3. I am happy for the positive results as if I really have helped in the treatment.

Comment: 4. I am as happy about the positive results as if I really had helped with the treatment.

Comment: What if I write this instead, I felt great as if I really had helped in this treatment?

Comment: There needs to be some punctuation between 'great' and 'as if'.

Comment: Ok let me write down the sentence, “I felt great when I saw the doctors reactions, as if I had personally helped in the treatment.” What do you think? Is it grammatically correct?

Comment: I'd use a dash (or a full stop followed by a fragment in informal writing), and _doctors_ needs an apostrophe.

Comment: Thank you. “I felt great, when I saw the doctors’ reactions, as if I had personally helped in the treatment.” Am I getting it now?

Comment: This is acceptable, but I've said what I'd use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An ["as if" clause](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/55279/tenses-after-as-if) is a perfect example of a contrary-to-fact statement that should be in the subjunctive. Since the imaginary event would have happened in the past, the tense looks like the past perfect, but is actually the past subjunctive. I would also suggest a couple of stylistic changes:

I am *as* happy about the results as if I had *personally* helped with the treatment.

Comment: What if write, I felt great as if I had personally helped in the treatment. Is it correct?

Comment: Again, I would say "as great as if..." but yes, it's correct.